# HealthKit Authorization Status Not Working

Tags: swift, healthkit

I want to be able to tell if the user has allowed my app to read their health data.  I found some code that seems to be doing just that, however, whenever I call the function, it always prints "Denied", instead of "Authorized", even though I am allowing it on my test device.  Here's my code:

```
func checkAuthorization() {
    let authorizationStatus = healthStore.authorizationStatus(for: HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis)!)
    if authorizationStatus == HKAuthorizationStatus.sharingAuthorized {
        print("Authorized")
    } else if authorizationStatus == HKAuthorizationStatus.sharingDenied {
        print("Denied")
    } else {
        print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little confusing, but it's behaving as designed. Check out the existing StackOverlow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076655/healthkit-authorisation-status-is-always-1/29128231#29128231

Comment: @Allan Thanks -- so is there any way for me to be able to tell if I have been granted permission?  Because then I would want to display a message asking the user to go into settings and allow me to read their health data.

Comment: Correct, by design you cannot tell whether the user has granted read authorization.

Comment: @Allan OK - thanks for the help.  I know Apple says that the purpose is privacy, but I don't understand why knowing whether or not I even have data is a matter of personal privacy...