# Health kit permission returns wrong value ios Bug?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Hey there  let come straight to the point

Issue is When User **Denied the permission** for health kit ask using `requestAuthorization` and then later  **grant the permission from settings**  but `authorizationStatus` ([Doc)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614154-authorizationstatus) return **sharingdenied**  even though permission granted

Steps to reproduce

Add following to ask the permission and press don't allow

```
 class func authorizeHealthKit(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {

    guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
        completion(false,HealthkitSetupError.notAvailableOnDevice)
        return
    }

    guard   let dateOfBirth = HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .dateOfBirth),
            let bloodType = HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .bloodType),
            let gender = HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .biologicalSex),

            let bodyMassIndex = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMassIndex),
            let height = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height),
            let bodyMass = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass),
            let activeEnergy = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)


    else {
        completion(false,HealthkitSetupError.dataTypeNotAvailable)
        return
    }





    let healthKitTypesToWrite:Set<HKSampleType> = [bodyMassIndex,
                                                    activeEnergy,
                                                    HKObjectType.workoutType()
                                                    ]

    let healthKitTypesToRead:Set<HKObjectType> = [dateOfBirth,
                                                  bloodType,
                                                  gender,
                                                  height,
                                                  bodyMass,
                                                  HKSampleType.workoutType()

                                                    ]


    HKHealthStore().requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypesToWrite, read: healthKitTypesToRead) { (granted, error) in
        completion(granted,error)
    }
```

Now Open health kit application (in source tab) and allow all permissions

back to application and

add following code

```
 let array = [HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .dateOfBirth),
                 HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .bloodType),
                 HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .biologicalSex),

                 HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMassIndex),
                 HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height),
                 HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass),
                 HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)]


    for item in array {

        let type =  store.authorizationStatus(for: item!)

        switch type  {
        case .sharingDenied:
            print("Sharing Denied \(item)")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not Determined \(item)")
        case .sharingAuthorized:
            print("Authorized \(item)")

        }

    }
```

You will see some of the values is  **Authorized** but most of are  **Sharing Denied** However you can read data from health kit

Please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HealthKit Authorisation Status is always 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076655/healthkit-authorisation-status-is-always-1)

Comment: facing the same problem

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper Health kit doesn't provide that user has granted read permission or not :(

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya so what is use of ```HKAuthorizationStatus```

Comment: @MeetIosDeveloper it is for write permission :) , Apple never reveals whether the user has granted read permission or not.